# MYSQL updating data from other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like of this structure:

```
content (content_id, content_type, user_id, time, comment_count)

comments (comment_id, content_id, userid, comment, comment_time)
```

What I wold like to do is update the comments_count field with sum of comments i.e COUNT(content_id) from the comments table.

I am not able to figure out the right syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE content c1 SET comment_count=(
    SELECT COUNT(c2.content_id) FROM comments c2 
    WHERE c1.content_id = c2.content_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Cross Table Update with MySQLCross Table Update with MySQL](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/mysql/cross-table-update/)

```
UPDATE product p, productPrice pp
SET pp.price = pp.price * 0.8
WHERE p.productId = pp.productId
AND p.dateCreated < '2004-01-01'
```

Comment: thanks for the help michael, i know this but im confused with using the COUNT() function.